# TypeError: change_email() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, pip, steam

so... pip steam, pls, help!
after start, it's given me an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/viznu/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/Python/sssteam.py", line 42, in
>   
>       sc.change_email(password=passwd, email='mail', code=code_mail) TypeError: change_email() missing 1 required
>   positional argument: 'self'

error:

```
import steam.webauth as wa
from steam.client import SteamClient as sc

#---------------------------------
#---------------------------------
login = 'login'

passwd = '12345' 
#---------------------------------
#---------------------------------

user = wa.WebAuth(login, passwd)

try:
    user.login()
    if wa.steam.webauth.LoginIncorrect:
        print('ERROR!, please, check password!')
except wa.CaptchaRequired:
    print(user.captcha_url)
    # ask a human to solve captcha
    captcha = input('Print captcha')
    user.login(captcha=capthca)

except wa.EmailCodeRequired:
    code_mail = input('Please, type your guard.\n')
    user.login(email_code=code_mail)

except wa.TwoFactorCodeRequired:
    code_2fa = input('Please, type your guard.\n')
    user.login(twofactor_code=code_2fa)


except wa.HTTPError:
    print('Error, please, check data\nError:', wa.HTTPError)


print('Success! You connected to steam id: "',user.steam_id,'"')

mail = 'mail@mail.com'
change = input("Please, type key\n1. Change mail and password\n2. Change mail\n")
if wa.EmailCodeRequired:

    sc.change_email(password=passwd, email='mail', code=code_mail)
elif wa.TwoFactorCodeRequired:
    sc.change_email(password=passwd, email='mail', code=code_2fa)

user.session.get('https://store.steampowered.com/account/history/')
# OR
```

Comment: You need to create a `SteamClient` first. You can't call methods on the class; you have to have an instance.

Comment: Actually you can. But not in this case.

Comment: There's a reason why the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests: "Class names should normally use the CapWords convention" and function and variable names "[...] should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores [...]". You renamed the class `SteamClient` as `sc`. Follow the Style Guide and you will see problems like that much faster.